# Chemistry formulae are not rendered correctly on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Official SEx app, version 1.0.35. Android version 4.2.1. When viewing Chemistry SE questions, the tag `\ce` is visible and is rendered in red, `{aligned}` environment doesn't render at all.

This may be a low priority item since the equations are perfectly visible in Firefox (29.0). However, working inside the app is much more convenient.

A sample Q&A where the bug is manifested: [Can water be ignited in an ozone atmosphere?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10716/can-water-be-ignited-in-an-ozone-atmosphere)

While I'm at it want to thank the devs for the app. Neat and slim, and really handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantastic catch! We were forgetting to bring in the MathJax chemistry plugin, which is the only single extra MathJax plugin we use other than the built in ones that we use everywhere else. As of version 1.0.39 coming sometime this week, here's what the question looks like:

[image]